# CGroup Debian 9 (4.9.82) won't work

Tags: debian, cgroups

i want to use cgroup to manage memory of specific processes.
I install cgroup-tools, enabled the memory controller in /etc/default/grub with
 `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"`

after this is update-grub.
created a group

```
cgcreate -g memory:1024
```

set my limit

```
 cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=1G 1024
```

and put the running process pid with cgclassify to the group

```
cgclassify -g memory:1024 $( pidof myprocess )
```

The process is ignoring the Limit, but the pid is in memory/1024/tasks
Where is my mistake?

Comment: What does /etc/cgrules.conf look like?

Comment: my /etc/cgrules.conf
`group 1024 {
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = "3G";
  }            
}`

Comment: But you're trying to set it to 1G?

Comment: i set now the cgrules.conf to 'group 1024 { memory { memory.limit_in_bytes = "1G"; } }' still the same problem. 
The running processes are using 1,6G and 2,6G, with the given limits.

Comment: Try amending the /etc/cgrules.conf file directly

Comment: Same result, the processes are running with much more than "allowed".

Comment: These aren't systemd based processes by any chance?

Comment: Sadly not, Need cgroups.